# How to render variable of if-else block in Yii

Tags: yii

I am new in Yii.I have if-else block  in an action and i need to render the value of the variable. But its showing error "Undefined variable". How it can be done??

Please help. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: can you add the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First declare the variable before the if else statement,
Then change that variable's value as per your if else statment 
Then Pass that variable to render. Suppose your variable name is $model, then your render code would be

```
$this->render('index.php', array('model' => $model));
```

In your view, you can access that variable with $model variable name.